# Sprint MVC tries to get resources with session id

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, jsessionid, java-resources

When I load my Spring MVC site, spring:url appends `jsessionid` to the resource sources and they will not be found.

This only happens the first time opening it. When reloading the site, it isn't there and the page loads correctly. Also every time, when reloading, even with deleting the caches, the resources load correctly.

I implemented Spring MVC in my project. My resources are located in `webapp/resources/core`.

My Spring MVC Config handles the resources like this:

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

I try to load the JavaScript in my JSP file with spring:url

```
<spring:url value="resources/core/js/starter.js" var="starterJs"/>
<script src="${starterJs}" type="module"></script>
```

The first time loading the webpage, the `jsessionid` gets appended to all the resource paths.
With that, the resources aren't getting loaded and the page has neither any JavaScript nor its CSS.

```html
<script src="resources/core/js/starter.js;jsessionid=F089849888EFF0CAF599C7BFEDC07792" type="module"></script>
```

After reloading the page, the session id isn't there anymore and the resources get loaded correctly.
Even after reloading with `[CTRL] + [SHIFT] + r` the jsessionid is not added and everything loads as expected.

Comment: Add `<%@ page session="false" %>` to your page and see if that helps. This disables the implicit session creation for that JSP page. If you have a custom header you include you might want to add it in there.

Comment: Thank you, that completely solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP pages implicitly create a HTTP Session. Initially there is no cookie (the most used way to manage sessions) so it will append the session identifier to the URL.

You can disable implicit session creation by specifing `session="false"` in your `page` directive on top of your JSP>

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```